How to right align values regardless of barcharts width?
I'm working with Apache echarts on horizontal bar charts. I am trying to right align the value of each bar chart but I wasn't able to find an example and after review API and playing around with the chart options, I'm not able to determine how to do this.
Is this possible?


Since you didnt share any code I can only guess what your chart looks like. Considering the image and that you added the label bar-chart I am assuming that it is a horizontal bar chart with very small bars. For bar charts there exists the property labelLayout which allows to position the labels based on absolute or relative pixel values.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: { type: 'value' },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
      label: { show: true },
      labelLayout: { x: '95%' }
    }
  ]
};


EDIT:
Here is another example which hopefully fits your needs. It makes use of a second bar series to mimick the background and uses labelLayout as a callback function.
Example:
const xAxisLength = 1500;
const data = [
  [820, 0, 'name1'],
  [832, 1, 'name2'],
  [901, 2, 'name3'],
  [934, 3, 'name4'],
  [1290, 4, 'name5'],
  [1330, 5, 'name6'],
  [1320, 6, 'name7']
];

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    show: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    show: false
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      data: data,
      itemStyle: { color: 'lightgreen' },
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.data[2];
        }
      },
      labelLayout: function (params) {
        const margin = 5;
        const bar = params.rect;
        const label = params.labelRect;
        return {
          x: bar.x + margin,
          y: bar.y - label.height - margin
        };
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      data: data.map((item) => xAxisLength - item[0]),
      barWidth: '20%',
      itemStyle: { color: 'grey' },
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return '$' + (xAxisLength - params.value);
        }
      },
      labelLayout: function (params) {
        const margin = 5;
        const bar = params.rect;
        const label = params.labelRect;
        return {
          x: bar.x + bar.width - label.width - margin,
          y: bar.y - label.height - margin
        };
      }
    }
  ]
};



Thanks Matthias,
I could have provided some code but outside the horizontal bar graph, i'm fairly certain i'm not doing it correctly. I appreciate you answering.
I reviewed your example, much better then what I have currently.
Small edge:
ex: if data was data: [820, 832, 901000, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
I could set labellayout.x to be lower then any realistic number but curious if there is an auto way to do this.
your solution solves the window width issue I was having. Is a way to always have it align right? (I need to review labellayout docs again).
Thank you

Its not quite clear to me what 'align right' means for you. On the right side of the grid? Right next to the bar?

sorry for the confusions. Same location for $ values as my screenshot, but the entire value shown. Regardless of the amount.
I believe your solution with labelLayout: { x: '95%' } pretty much solves it. it still does "stick" to the right but its much better then what I previously has.
Ideally its this format
| test Name                       $3000  |
| -----------------------------    |
| test2                                $2000 |
| --------------------                   |
| test3                                   $100 |
| ----                                              |

formatting is lost in the comment.
For each record it would be: Left align name, right align dollar value. Bar is below.

@SegFaultDev I edited my answer with a new example. Is this what you are looking for?
